how to use vueUse/nuxt useSwipe in a v-for loop
I am trying to make a v-for loop list, that lists over my wine bottle. I want to add the ability for each bottle to have its own useSwipe element to which i can swipe over the div to then show a button that can be clicked to remove the bottle from my cellar. Within the list each bottle has a bottleId and i only want one bottle to be swiped at a time, and then if a bottle with a different id is clicked or touched it will close the bottle that is showing the button.
This is the list code, i have tried making the functions and have a basic one working currently but sometimes when another list item is clicked it will remove the bottle without displaying the button.
<div v-for="(bottle, index) in filteredBottles" :key="bottle.bottleId">
  <div>
    {{ bottle.bottle_name }}
  </div>
  <button @click="deleteBottle(bottle.bottleId)">Delete Bottle</button>
</div>


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There's nothing wrong in the snippet that you posted

You could just make a bottle div into a separate component. Component will handle logic on it's own as if it was singular, and you wil render v-for in a parent component
